# Why are there &nbsp; characters in so many random places?

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm working on merging two branches of a web application and I've noticed there are a *ton* of `&nbsp;` all over the ASPX pages.

I've read that certain versions of IE / Netscape have issues with empty table data tags like so:

`<TD></TD>`

and "require" an `&nbsp;` in between to display as desired but I'm finding them all over the place, one or more before and or after various ASP controls, none surrounding others. Some prefacing labels / "floating" text (for lack of a better word) like `<TD>&nbsp;Some Text</TD>`

It's making this whole process painfully difficult and slow when WinMerge is telling me two lines are different but it's really just because there's an arbitrary `&nbsp;` thrown in somewhere and there's no easy way for me to get a graphical representation of the different versions in SVN.

Is there any real rule of thumb for when or how to use the character? The web application is IE only, primarily targeting versions 7-9 or versions newer than that in Compatibility Mode. Chrome / FireFox etc. unsupported, if that helps narrow down reasoning behind its use.

Comment: The only time it is really appropriate to use a `&nbsp;` is between two words (such as a name) that should be kept together despite word wrapping. Other uses are usually hacks and better dealt with using CSS.

Comment: it's a historical artifact that should be  killed off. old rendering engines treated `<td></td>` as (if they understood css) the equivalent of `display: hidden`, and so your fancy table-based layout would have a hole because the browser didn't draw in that empty cell's borderse.

Comment: If you're trying to check whether two lines are the same, regardless of nbsps, I'd recommend replacing all `&nbsp;`s with normal space characters, trimming the spaces on either end of the string (not familiar with ASP, but most languages have a .trim() or .strip() method for strings), and *then* doing the comparison.

Comment: @oxguy3 That might work, just a simple Ctrl-H and replace `&nbspc` with an empty string or something. I just wasn't sure if there was a reason they were everywhere for seemingly no reason, to a less experienced web dev.

Answer (score 2):

They're often abused for poor-man's padding. They can also serve a legitimate purpose as most browsers will only recognize a single empty space character between two words. If you actually need several, you need to string together multiple `&nbsp;`s.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using WinMerge and coming up against issues like this quite a lot, you could configure a filter so that you can ignore the non-breaking spaces in HTML/ASPX files.

Details can be found here: http://manual.winmerge.org/Filters.html